# K-D Trees comparison

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, kdtree

I am doing a report regarding K-D Trees. There is a part there wherein I am tasked to compare K-D Trees to other data structures such as Lists, Maps, Arrays, etc. However, I have no idea how to compare it with other Data structures. What should I do and implement?

Comment: As a rough guideline you should mention their properties, purposes, time/space complexities of basic operations (insert, search etc.) and most suitable usage situations. That said, K-D trees serve a very different purpose to the generic container structures you mentioned there.

Comment: if possible create a small program and write down the time it took for the program to run with the use of following data structures and based on that data you can create a graph, it would look more nice as it shows that you have taken a effort towards understanding the data structures

Comment: @meowgoesthedog In which data structure should I compare K-D Trees then?

Comment: @nkpg K-D trees are most commonly used for *spatial division*, thus it is best to compare them to e.g. Octrees, Quadtrees, grids, BSP's and BVH's. Operations with these structures typically include e.g. ray-casting, nearest-neighbor searching, overlap detection.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog In addition, I created a program that would get time complexity of K-D Trees and other data structures. I am boggled that time complexities of insert and search of K-D Trees are higher than Arrays, ArrayLists and Maps. Did it in Java

Comment: @zenwraight Thanks, I greatly appreciated your suggestion.

Comment: @nkpg as I have said, I'm pretty sure it doesn't make much sense to compare K-D trees to e.g. arrays, as they serve different purposes.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Ok, thank you!

Comment: A bit outside your request, but have a look at www.tinspin.org, it provides a performance comparison of kd-trees with other spatial indexes, such as R+Trees, Quadtrees, STR-Tree, PH-Tree, ...

Comment: @TilmannZ Hello, does it contain K-D Tree?

Comment: In the case of KD-Trees it only provides wrappers, specifically for the two implementations by [Levy](http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/software/kd/) and [Savarese](http://www.savarese.com/software/libssrckdtree-j/)